# How to convert from Jama Matrix object to double[][] - Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, inverse

I have an object Matrix from the package **JAMA**, where I stored a double[][] array. I want to return the values of the method Matrix.inverse().

How can I pass values from a Matrix object to a double[][] array?

```
double K[][] = {{1,5,3,4} , {1,10,4,3} , {1,40,232,4} , {32,434,23,5}};
Matrix GetInverse = new Matrix(K);

double returnValues[][] = GetInverse.inverse(); // ---?----
```

Comment: What does the `Matrix` class look like?

Comment: Is from the package JAMA. Unfortunately, they don't have good documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>It's hard to know how to answer this without knowing more about the `Matrix` class itself. The best approach is likely to be to write a `toDoubleArray()` method in the `Matrix` class, which would operate in a way similar to how the `toArray()` method words for the classes that implement `List` (which return an `Object[]`).</strike>

It might be as simple as returning the internal `double[][]` stored in the `Matrix` instance.

Since your edit clarified that you are using the JAMA class, you can simply do this:

```
double returnValues[][] = GetInverse.inverse().getArray();
```

Since you are not keeping a reference to the inverse `Matrix` object, this is safe. In general, though, to be safe you should not access the internal array directly and instead use the `getArrayCopy()` instead of `getArray()`.